# Set terraform local for all items in a map that doesn't match on a list

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to get a local set in my terraform code to compare a passed in list of strings to to a map and return anything in the map that doesn't match on the list of strings.

For example, if I had the below variable

```
variable "enabled_rules" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "rules to disable."
}
variable "rules" {
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    "911100" = "8ac8bc2a661e475d940980f9317f28e1"
    "913100" = "53065ac9bd9449f3895f1865467a0e6a"
    "913110" = "c22e77bece6a43f3aa437a5eda9953ce"
}
```

And I passed into this `enabled_rules = ["911100","913100"]`, I'd want the local I'm trying to create to equal "913110".

Sorry if this is a silly question, I've been writing terraform for days and my brain is fried.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with a [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) using [contains](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/contains).

```
locals {
  enabled_rules = ["911100", "913100"]

  rules = {
    "911100" = "8ac8bc2a661e475d940980f9317f28e1"
    "913100" = "53065ac9bd9449f3895f1865467a0e6a"
    "913110" = "c22e77bece6a43f3aa437a5eda9953ce"
  }

  disabled = [for k, _ in local.rules : k if !contains(local.enabled_rules, k)]
}

output "disabled" {
  value = local.disabled
}
```

output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + disabled = [
      + "913110",
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions for set mathematics for this. Specifically, you are looking for the complement of `enabled_rules` and the keys for `rules`. For the given example values above, this would be:

```
setsubtract(keys(var.rules), var.enabled_rules) # => ['913110']
```